# Reading/importing fixed range of rows from multiple files

Tags: r, csv

I want to read several a fixed range of rows from multiple .csv-files and at the same time use parameters from the file names to build a new table.

More specific: In one map, I have several files, named in the format `OutputSalphaRbeta_MgammaTTttTCtcSGsg.txt` where alpha, beta, gamma, tt, tc and sg are varying (example: `OutputS4R1_M1TT21333TC21333SG21333.txt`). I want to read the data on rows 12-64000 from 120 files, calculate frequency tables for each of them (within distance_interval), and then make a new table where S alpha, Mgamma, distance_interval, average frequency. This means I need R t

I tried to set the workspace first, then initialize the parameters and read the table:

```
setwd("G:/Taita Seed Dispersal_-_RUNSterugkeergedrag\\3.2_R_all_years_(RW)\\0-even_distrib_21333HT-SG-HT")

alpha <-'4' # initialize parameter of file names: OutputSalphaRbeta_MgammaTTttTCtcSGsg.txt
beta <- '1'
gamma <- '1'
tt <- '21333'
tc <- '21333'
sg <- '21333'


data <-
  read.table(file=paste("OutputS",alpha,"R",beta,"_M",gamma,"TT",tt,"TC",tc,"SG",sg, ".txt", sep=""))
```

but I get the error message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

and the warning message:

> In file(file, "rt") :
>    cannot open file 'OutputS4R1_M1TT21333TC21333SG21333.txt': No such file or directory.

Following recommendations on other posts, I tried `getwd()` already, but many other suggestions that I found when typing this error message can't be used here because they only work with single csv-files.
Any suggestions on what goes wrong or on how do proceed please?

Comment: do you see that file when run command `list.files()`

Comment: Does this work? 'df <- read.table("/file_path/filename.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")[c(12:6400), ]'

Comment: With list.files() I do get a list of all maps where the files I need are in, so no error message. With 'df <- read.table("/file_path/filename.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")[c(12:6400), ]' (for 1 single .txt-file as an esample)  I do get the same error message as before...

Comment: if I make a txt file on my desktop and call it trial4, i can open it using the following code: `setwd("/Users/user/Desktop/")

a <- "trial" 
b <- "4"

df.000 <- read.table(paste(a,b, ".txt", sep=""), header=TRUE, sep="") [, c(1:2)]` this last bit can be tweaked to specify which columns and rows you want to read in.

Comment: Maybe the .txt-files themselves cause problems? I renamed my file ‘trial4’ such that your program can be used, but for print() I now get  ‘Error in print.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default’. My data (row 1-3):
        initx  inity   dropx   dropy   displacement  habitat   vector   gutpassage_t  germinated   survived
        12        14        16        13      4.12         0         1         3      TRUE     FALSE
        14        11        13        11      1.00         2         1         3      FALSE     FALSE

Comment: The example works well now with the data only, thanks for the advice. However, it doesn't work with the files with line 1-12 being full text (like a legend above a table). I tried             subset(df.000[12:10,], select = c(5)) but get the message Error: unexpected symbol in:"df.000 <- read.table(paste(a,b, ".txt", sep="")